# Coefficients of a linear combination of eigenfunctions

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to show that given $\psi(x)=c_0\psi_0(x)+c_1\psi_1(x)$, where all functions are normalized and additionally that $\psi_0$ and $\psi_1$ are eigenfunctions of an arbitrary operator, that $|c_0|^2+|c_1|^2 = 1$.

From what I understand, the eigenfunctions of a given operator should all be orthogonal to one  another (that is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi_i(x)^\star\psi_j(x) = 0$, if $i \neq j$), so it makes sense on some level that a linear combination of them that is still normalized in and of itself (specified in the problem) would have a 'magnitude' of 1, so the length of the vector determined by the coefficients $c_0$ and $c_1$ would be 1 (or is my logic totally faulty?).

I'm not sure how to actually demonstrate this, however.

Comment: How do you normalize, say $\sin(x)$ ? Are your coefficients functions too?

Comment: @percusse Normalizing such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\psi(x)|^2 = 1$ (which you can't do with $sin$).  The coefficients are constants.

Comment: @percusse: You don't normalize $\sin$ over $\mathbb{R}$, you do that over some finite interval with length a multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: You've left out some hypotheses.  The correct statement is that $\langle \psi_i, \psi_j \rangle = 0$ if $\psi_i$ and $\psi_j$ are eigenfunctions of a _self-adjoint_ operator for _different_ eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You demonstrate it via $$1=\langle\psi,\psi\rangle=\langle c_0\psi_0+c_1\psi_1,c_0\psi_0+c_1\psi_1\rangle$$ $$=\langle c_0\psi_0,c_0\psi_0\rangle+\langle c_1\psi_1,c_0\psi_0\rangle+\langle c_0\psi_0,c_1\psi_1\rangle+\langle c_1\psi_1,c_1\psi_1\rangle$$
$$=c_0c_0^*\langle\psi_0,\psi_0\rangle+c_1c_0^*\langle\psi_1,\psi_0\rangle+c_0c_1^*\langle\psi_0,\psi_1\rangle+c_1c_1^*\langle\psi_1,\psi_1\rangle$$
$$=|c_0|^2+|c_1|^2.$$
Above we used the facts $\langle\psi_0,\psi_0\rangle=\langle\psi_1,\psi_1\rangle=1$ and $\langle\psi_1,\psi_0\rangle=\langle\psi_0,\psi_1\rangle=0$, as well as basic features of the [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) (linearity and conjugate symmetry):
$$\langle u+v,w\rangle=\langle u,w\rangle+\langle v,w\rangle$$
$$\langle u,v+w\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle+\langle u,w\rangle$$
$$\langle au,bv\rangle=ab^*\langle u,v\rangle$$
with $a$ and $b$ scalars and $z^*$ denoting complex conjugation.

This generalizes to arbitrary linear combinations of normalized orthogonal vectors:
$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\psi_i \right\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n|c_i|^2 \text{  when }\langle\psi_i,\psi_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}.$$

Comment: I was just starting to write it out, but with a heinous abuse of mathematical syntax (e.g. $|c_0\psi_0(x)+c_1\psi_1(x)|^2 = |c_0\psi_0(x)|^2 + 2|c_0\psi_0(x)||c_1\psi_1(x)| +|c_1\psi_1(x)|^2$)

Comment: @NickT: Ah, careful: that $|c_0\psi_0||c_1\psi_1|$ is actually incorrect.

Comment: Could you elaborate a touch; I'm out of my element :(  Is it because they're not necessarily communicative?

Comment: @NickT: It's because $\langle a,b\rangle$ does not evaluate to $|a| |b|$. (Or were you asking about my answer in general?)